# Usage of Regular Expression Extractor JMeter?

Tags: testing, jmeter

Using Regular Extractor in JMeter, I need to get the value of "`fullBkupUNIXTime`" from the below response,

```
{"fullBackupTimeString":["Mon 10 Apr 2017 14:14:36"],"fullBkupUNIXTime":["1491833676"],"fullBackupDirName":["10_04_2017_0636"]}
```

I tried with Ref Name as `time` and 
Regular Expression: `"fullBkupUNIXTime": "([0-9])" and "(.+?)"`
and pass them as input for 2nd request `${time}`

The above 2 two doesn't work out for me.
Please Help me out of this.

Comment: Use this expression to retrieve fullBkupUNIXTime. You need to add escape character \ in the expression.

\"fullBkupUNIXTime\":\[\"(.+?)\"

Comment: let me know if above answer works for you. I will post it in the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest to get some additional insights about **JMeter Regex Extractor** by reading this guide on [JMeter Regex Extractor](https://octoperf.com/blog/2017/09/07/jmeter-regular-expression-extractor/). It gives some useful real-life examples.

Comment: I have used JSON extractor for the above and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: why not just use [this thing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)?

Then, if you firm with your RegExp adventure to get happen.

First expression is not going to work because you've defined it to match exactly one `[0-9]` charcter.

Add the appropriate repetition character, like `"fullBkupUNIXTime": "([0-9]+)"`.

And basically it make sense to tell the engine to stop at first narrowest match too: `"fullBkupUNIXTime": "([0-9]+?)"`

Next, make sure you're handling space chars between key and value and colon mark properly. Better mark them explicitly, if any, with `\s`

And last but not least: make sure you're properly handle multiple lines (if appropriate, of course). Add the `(?m)` modifier to your expression.
And/or `(?im)` to be not case-sensitive, in addition.

Answer (score 0):

`[` is a reserve character in regex, you need to escape it, in your case use:

```
Regular Expression fullBkupUNIXTime":\["(\d+)

Template: $1$

Match No.:  1
```